# SAP Hybris/Commerce Cloud + WRO4J - Failed to generate all_responsive.js bundle

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, wro4j

I'm getting error when try to enable wro4j on a SAP Hybris Project.
All the bundles are genarated pretty, but the all_responsive.js bundle show the error below.

```
ERROR [hybrisHTTP5] [ExceptionHandlingProcessorDecorator] Failed to process the resource: ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.Resource@19365f9b[true,JS,all_responsive] using processor: ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.impl.js.JSMinProcessor@6de12d00. Reason: null
ERROR [hybrisHTTP5] [WroFilter] Exception occured
 ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: null
    at ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException.wrap(WroRuntimeException.java:69) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException.wrap(WroRuntimeException.java:54) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.impl.js.JSMinProcessor.process(JSMinProcessor.java:60) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.SupportAwareProcessorDecorator.process(SupportAwareProcessorDecorator.java:39) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ExceptionHandlingProcessorDecorator.process(ExceptionHandlingProcessorDecorator.java:56) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.BenchmarkProcessorDecorator.process(BenchmarkProcessorDecorator.java:44) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.ProcessorDecorator.process(ProcessorDecorator.java:86) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.decorator.DefaultProcessorDecorator.process(DefaultProcessorDecorator.java:42) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.group.processor.GroupsProcessor$1.process(GroupsProcessor.java:134) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.group.processor.GroupsProcessor.applyPostProcessors(GroupsProcessor.java:115) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.group.processor.GroupsProcessor.process(GroupsProcessor.java:84) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.cache.support.DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.loadValue(DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.java:101) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.cache.support.DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.loadValue(DefaultSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.java:35) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.cache.support.AbstractSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.get(AbstractSynchronizedCacheStrategyDecorator.java:55) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.ResourceBundleProcessor.serveProcessedBundle(ResourceBundleProcessor.java:63) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.manager.WroManager.process(WroManager.java:159) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter.processRequest(WroFilter.java:339) [wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter.doFilter(WroFilter.java:294) [wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367) [catalina.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:885) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1693) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.83]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.83]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.support.JSMin$UnterminatedStringLiteralException
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.support.JSMin.action(JSMin.java:151) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.support.JSMin.jsmin(JSMin.java:285) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at ro.isdc.wro.model.resource.processor.impl.js.JSMinProcessor.process(JSMinProcessor.java:56) ~[wro4j-core-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    ... 40 more
WARN  [hybrisHTTP5] [WroFilter] Cannot process. Proceeding with chain execution.
```

(Note: the "... 40 more" is not clickable.)

When I try to access the page, i receive a "Server error" text on the all_responsive.js request.
[image: Server error on page]

Probably is a JS created "out of the pattern" but idk how to debug this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This already happened to me once, it was due to a literal that wasn't close on the same line, when you use literals ` and you don't close them on the same line WRO4J fails to compress the JS,
For example, if you have this on your code :

```
` JS code
 `
```

Try doing it like this instead :

```
` JS code `
```

So check on your recent JS code if you have something like this

UPDATE :

This link might be usefull too : https://me.sap.com/notes/2864767

Comment: i've checked all js made since last deploy and the problem is when use template strings like this: `foo ${var.length > 10 ? 'bar' : 'false bar'}`
making inline conditionals.
Btw thanks for your help!